# script not working as intended with barba.js

Tags: javascript, barbajs

i tried using `barba.Dispatcher.on('transitionCompleted', function(currentStatus, oldStatus, container)` to no avail. the divs should cycle when clicking on the dialogue box. here is the full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>1</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://files.catbox.moe/h33w19.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/37b69e3f02.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@barba/core"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
    <div data-barba="wrapper">
        <main data-barba="container" class="container">
            
            <div class="icon"><img src="https://files.catbox.moe/v1ccbr.png" width="400"></div>

            <div class="dialoguewrap">
                <div class="arrowleft" style="visibility:hidden;"><a href="/index.html" data-direction="prev"><img src="https://files.catbox.moe/mosfgm.png"></a></div>
                
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="header">1/6</div>
                        Gabriel jolts awake. "That dream again..."<br><br>
                        He's been having these strange nightmares. 
                        <div class="footer"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="box hidden">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="header">2/6</div>
                        Each and every nightmare starts and ends the same way. He would be going about his daily life when suddenly abnormal occurrences would happen. 
                        <div class="footer"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="box hidden">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="header">3/6</div>
                        Once it was the beginning of World War 3. Another time it was a world-ending meteor from space. The strangest had to be the one where aliens attacked.
                        <div class="footer"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="box hidden">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="header">4/6</div>
                        And every time, without fail, he would die at the end.
                        <div class="footer"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="box hidden">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="header">5/6</div>
                        He was tired of these nightmares.  
                        <div class="footer"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="box hidden">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <div class="header">6/6</div>
                        Gabriel decides to put it all past him for the time being. He gets up from bed and gets ready for school. It's his last year of high school. Only a few more weeks before he graduates.
                        <div class="footer"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <div class="arrowright"><a href="/pages/page2.html" data-direction="next"><img src="https://files.catbox.moe/mosfgm.png"></a></div>
            </div>
            
            <script src="/scripts/main.js"></script>  
            <script>barba.Pjax.start();</script>
            <script>
                barba.Dispatcher.on('transitionCompleted', function(currentStatus, oldStatus, container) {

                var hints = $('.box');
                var i = 0;

                $('.inner').on('click', function(){
                    i = (i + 1) % hints.length;
                    hints.hide().eq(i).show();
                });


                }(barba, jQuery));
            </script>
        </main>
    </div>
   
        
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is a codepen. https://codepen.io/adilene/pen/ZEmEybM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it myself! i had to add a hook to call the function after every new page. here's the code:

```
function shuffle(){
    var hints = $('.box');
    var i = 0;

    $('.inner').on('click', function(){
        i = (i + 1) % hints.length;
        hints.hide().eq(i).show();
    })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    shuffle();
});

barba.hooks.after(() => {
    shuffle();
});                    

barba.init({

  transitions: [{
    name: 'opacity-transition',
    leave(data) {
      return gsap.to(data.current.container, {
        opacity: 0
      });
    },
    enter(data) {
      return gsap.from(data.next.container, {
        opacity: 0
      });
    }
  }]
    
});
```

i'll update the codepen to reflect my answer.